# Conditional expectation and Bayes' rule

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation, bayes-theorem

I saw this equation from a book:

$P(y \ | \ x) \ = \ \displaystyle \frac{\sum_s P(y, x, s)}{\sum_{y,s} P(y, x, s)}$

The author said this conditional expectation is based on the Bayes' rule, but I just couldn't get it. Would you please explain to me why the LHS equals to the RHS?

Comment: Are you familiar with the [law of total probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recall the definition of conditional probability; for two events $A,B$, we have

$$P(A\mid B)=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(A\cap B)+P(A^c\cap B)}$$

where the equality in the denominator is due to the law of total probability.

For random variables $X,Y$, the same expression would be

$$P(Y=y\mid X=x)=\frac{P(X=x,Y=y)}{P(X=x)}=\frac{P(X=x,Y=y)}{\sum_yP(X=x,Y=y)}$$

where $P(X=x,Y=y)$ is the joint probability that $X=x$ and $Y=y$.

Your question seems to consider a third random variable $S$, in which case you would expand each of the probabilities above (using the LoTP) to consider all possible values of $S$, so that

$$P(Y=y\mid X=x)=\frac{\sum_sP(X=x,Y=y,S=s)}{\sum_{y,s}P(X=x,Y=y,S=s)}$$

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation! Now I can see it!

Comment: BTW, is it true then Baye' law has really nothing to do with this equation, unless we argue that P(A ^ B) = P(B|A) P(A)?

Comment: I wouldn't say it has nothing to do with the equation, but at the same time you don't need to state Bayes' rule explicitly because everything you need follows from the definition of conditional probability together with the law of total probability.